# Can't Delete items from Animated List 'The getter 'currentState' was called on null. Receiver: null Tried calling: currentState'

Tags: flutter, dart

so I have an Animated list with bunch of items and a filter(Switch) the user can toggle, the filter will remove the items that are not needed but for some reason I keep getting:

> "The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown while handling a gesture:
> The getter 'currentState' was called on null. Receiver: null Tried
> calling: currentState",

but if i keep pressing the Switch the code does work.

this is the way I delete Items:

```
void removeItems(){
    if(onlyRight){
      for(int i = 0; i < mainItems.length; i++){
        QueList item = mainItems[i];
        if(item.isRight==false){
          mainItems.removeAt(i);
          _listKey.currentState!.removeItem(i, (context, animation) => QueViewWidget(
            item: item,
            animation: animation,
            onlyRight: onlyRight,
            onlyWrong: onlyWrong,
          )
          );
        }
      }
    }
    if(onlyWrong){
      for(int i = 0; i < mainItems.length; i++){
        QueList item = mainItems[i];
        if(item.isRight!=false){
          mainItems.removeAt(i);
          _listKey.currentState!.removeItem(i, (context, animation) => QueViewWidget(
            item: item,
            animation: animation,
            onlyRight: onlyRight,
            onlyWrong: onlyWrong,
          )
          );
        }
      }
    }
    if(onlyRight==false && onlyWrong == false){
      Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed('/view');
    }
  }
```

and this is the AnimatedList:

```
void removeItems(){
    if(onlyRight){
      for(int i = 0; i < mainItems.length; i++){
        QueList item = mainItems[i];
        if(item.isRight==false){
          mainItems.removeAt(i);
          _listKey.currentState!.removeItem(i, (context, animation) => QueViewWidget(
            item: item,
            animation: animation,
            onlyRight: onlyRight,
            onlyWrong: onlyWrong,
          )
          );
        }
      }
    }
    if(onlyWrong){
      for(int i = 0; i < mainItems.length; i++){
        QueList item = mainItems[i];
        if(item.isRight!=false){
          mainItems.removeAt(i);
          _listKey.currentState!.removeItem(i, (context, animation) => QueViewWidget(
            item: item,
            animation: animation,
            onlyRight: onlyRight,
            onlyWrong: onlyWrong,
          )
          );
        }
      }
    }
    if(onlyRight==false && onlyWrong == false){
      Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed('/view');
    }
  }
```

and lastly this is the whole script:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:liquid_swipe/liquid_swipe.dart';
import 'package:qudorat_app/prosses/card_que_view.dart';
import 'package:qudorat_app/prosses/question_list.dart';
import 'package:qudorat_app/prosses/temp_list.dart';

class ViewAnswers extends StatefulWidget {
  final GlobalKey<AnimatedListState> keyer;
  const ViewAnswers({required this.keyer});


  @override
  _ViewAnswersState createState() => _ViewAnswersState();
}

class _ViewAnswersState extends State<ViewAnswers> {

  bool onlyRight = false;
  bool onlyWrong = false;

  late GlobalKey<AnimatedListState> _listKey= widget.keyer;
  List<QueList> mainItems = [];

  List<QueList> items = List.from(queListItems);



  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    mainItems = items;
  }

  void removeItems(){
    if(onlyRight){
      for(int i = 0; i < mainItems.length; i++){
        QueList item = mainItems[i];
        if(item.isRight==false){
          mainItems.removeAt(i);
          _listKey.currentState!.removeItem(i, (context, animation) => QueViewWidget(
            item: item,
            animation: animation,
            onlyRight: onlyRight,
            onlyWrong: onlyWrong,
          )
          );
        }
      }
    }
    if(onlyWrong){
      for(int i = 0; i < mainItems.length; i++){
        QueList item = mainItems[i];
        if(item.isRight!=false){
          mainItems.removeAt(i);
          _listKey.currentState!.removeItem(i, (context, animation) => QueViewWidget(
            item: item,
            animation: animation,
            onlyRight: onlyRight,
            onlyWrong: onlyWrong,
          )
          );
        }
      }
    }
    if(onlyRight==false && onlyWrong == false){
      Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed('/view');
    }
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print(mainItems.length);
    return LiquidSwipe(pages: [
      Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.amber,
        body: Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
              gradient: LinearGradient(
                  begin: Alignment.topLeft,
                  end: Alignment.bottomRight,
                  colors: [Colors.pink, Colors.amber])),
          child: Center(
            child: SafeArea(
              child: Column(children: [
                Row(
                  children: [
                    Expanded(
                        child: Container(
                      margin: EdgeInsets.all(8),
                      padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(8, 12, 8, 12),
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25.0),
                        boxShadow: [
                          BoxShadow(
                              color: Colors.black54,
                              blurRadius: 15.0,
                              offset: Offset(0.0, 0.75))
                        ],
                      ),
                      child: Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                        children: [
                          Switch(
                            activeColor: Colors.grey[800],
                            value: onlyRight,
                            onChanged: onlyWrong ? null: (b) {
                              setState(() {
                                onlyRight = b;
                                removeItems();

                              });
                            },
                          ),
                          Text(
                            "الإجابات \n الصحيحة",
                            textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
                            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                            style: TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.white,
                                fontFamily: "ArabicModern-Bold"),
                          ),
                          SizedBox(
                            width: 100,
                          ),
                          // add math arabic
                          Switch(
                            activeColor: Colors.grey[800],
                            value: onlyWrong,
                            onChanged: onlyRight ? null: (b) {
                              setState(() {
                                onlyWrong = b;
                                removeItems();

                              });
                            },
                          ),
                          Text(
                            "الإجابات \n الخاطئة",
                            textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
                            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                            style: TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.white,
                                fontFamily: "ArabicModern-Bold"),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    )),
                  ],
                ),
                Expanded(
                    child: Container(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
                  child: AnimatedList(
                    initialItemCount: mainItems.length,
                    key: _listKey,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index, animation) {
                      return QueViewWidget(
                        item: mainItems[index],
                        animation: animation,
                        onlyRight: onlyRight,
                        onlyWrong: onlyWrong,
                      );
                    },
                  ),
                ))
              ]),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ]);
  }
}
```

please if you have any idea on how to fix this help me because i have been trying to fix this for along time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution 1 if you have only one instance of ViewAnswers Widget**

I recommend you to define you're listKey as a static variable instead of passing it between widgets

```
class ViewAnswersState extends State<ViewAnswers> {
static GlobalKey<AnimatedListState> listKey = GlobalKey<AnimatedListState>();
...
```

and use it in top widgets like this

```
SignUpScreenState.listKey.method();
```

**Solution 2**

Edit your ViewAnswersState as follows

```
class ViewAnswersState extends State<ViewAnswers> {
    GlobalKey<AnimatedListState> listKey = GlobalKey<AnimatedListState>();
    
    addItem(x){
          // code to add item to be used parent class
          }
    doSometing(){//}
...
```

after this, in your parent widget when you want to create this ViewAnswers

```
GlobalKey<ViewAnswersState> viewAnswersKey = GlobalKey<ViewAnswersState>();
...
Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
 builder: (context) =>ViewAnswers(key:viewAnswersKey)));
```

then you can simply use functions inside ViewAnswersState

```
viewAnswersKey.currentState.addItem(x)
```

Comment: The code is working and the error is gone but now i have another issue
"Multiple widgets used the same GlobalKey.".

Comment: try solution #2

Comment: Thank you, this fixed my issue

Answer (score 0):

the `_listKey` is null, double check if the value passed to the constructor  `ViewAnswers()` is non-null or try to move the var init `_listKey= widget.keyer` to the initstate method

Comment: as in Sajad answer's the code is now working but i get "Multiple widgets used the same GlobalKey"

Comment: yup consider using a list of keys instead on one key and give each widget a unique key